# update UIViewController in Real Time from Popover Viewcontroller in Swift 4

Tags: swift, debugging, uiviewcontroller, scenekit, switchcontrol

right now i'm experimenting with SceneKit DebugOptions.
i'm trying to update/ show Scenekits Debug Options in real time, using switch controllers from a Popover ViewController.

i've tried many things, like UserDefaults, Delegation and Protocols, but stil i wasn't able to see the result in real time, every time i have to kill the app en relaunch it to see the results.

so, i would be greatfull if someone would have an answer to my question :D

[image]

**extension i added to my MainVC**

```
extension ViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, DebugOptions {

func wireFrameEnabled(enabled: Bool) {
    if enabled == true {
        print(enabled)
    }
}

func showCameraEnabled(enabled: Bool) {

}

func showAllDebugOptions(enabled: Bool) {

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let popoverController = segue.destination.popoverPresentationController, let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
    popoverController.delegate = self
    popoverController.sourceRect = button.bounds
    let debugMenuVC = popoverController.presentedViewController as! DebugMenuVC
    debugMenuVC.delegate? = self
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return .none
}
```

}

**Protocol**

```
protocol DebugOptions {
func wireFrameEnabled(enabled: Bool)
func showCameraEnabled(enabled: Bool)
func showAllDebugOptions(enabled: Bool)
```

}

**DebugMenuVC**

```
class DebugMenuVC: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var bgView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var showWireFrameSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var showCameraSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var showAllSwitch: UISwitch!

var delegate: DebugOptions?

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 300)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    buttonCheck()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


}

@IBAction func aSwitchBtnWasPressed( _ sender: UISwitch ) {
    if (sender.tag == 0) && (sender.isOn == true) {
        userDefaults.set(true, forKey: SHOW_WIRE_FRAME)
        delegate?.wireFrameEnabled(enabled: true)


    } else if (sender.tag == 0) && (sender.isOn == false) {
        userDefaults.set(false, forKey: SHOW_WIRE_FRAME)
        delegate?.wireFrameEnabled(enabled: false)

    }

}

func buttonCheck() {
    if userDefaults.bool(forKey: SHOW_WIRE_FRAME) == true{
        showWireFrameSwitch.isOn = true
    } else {
        showWireFrameSwitch.isOn = false
    }

}
```

}

Comment: show us the delegate way you have tried  , it's the right one for your case

Comment: @Sh_Khan i've updated my article/ Question

Comment: tried to print the delegate in the popup to verify it's not nil in **delegate?.wireFrameEnabled(enabled: true)** and **delegate?.wireFrameEnabled(enabled: false)**

Comment: the problem is, that the delegate is not being called in MainVieController!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in debubMenuVC.delegate shouldn't be an optional. thats the reason the delegation method always failed :D

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let popoverController = segue.destination.popoverPresentationController, let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
    popoverController.delegate = self
    popoverController.sourceRect = button.bounds
    let debugMenuVC = popoverController.presentedViewController as! DebugMenuVC
    debugMenuVC.delegate? = self
}
```